# Retrieve the filtered data from HTML table and format it into array

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, phpspreadsheet

I've been working on a function in a PHP system where I can filter the records and then export it to Excel that has a template using PHPSpreadSheet. My problem is that I don't know how to retrieve the filtered records as said in the title above. I think I'm missing something here in my code. This is my code in fetching the records from database into table.

```
<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db_ims");
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_par";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

      echo "<table id='myTable'>";
      echo "<thead><tr><th>Article</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Property Number</th>
      </tr></thead>";
      echo "<tbody>";
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['article'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['description'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['propertyNumber'] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      }
      echo "</tbody>";
      echo "</table>";

// Close the database connection
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
    <form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="filterTable()" placeholder="Search...">
    <input type="submit" id="generate" name="generate" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

This is my code in filtering the records:

```
<script>
function filterTable() {
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    for (var j = 0; j < td.length; j++) {
      txtValue = td[j].textContent || td[j].innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
        break;
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Lastly, this is the code in exporting the filtered table into excel using PHPSpreadSheet:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;

if (isset($_POST['generate'])) {


$spreadsheet = IOFactory::load('Template.xls');

//This is the part where I don't know what to put.
$data = array();


$worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$row = 10; // Start inserting data from row 10
foreach ($data as $item) {
    $worksheet->setCellValue('A'.$row, $item['article']);
    $worksheet->setCellValue('B'.$row, $item['description']);
    $worksheet->setCellValue('C'.$row, $item['propertyNumber']);
    // ...
    $row++;
}


$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
$writer->save('exported_file.xlsx');
}
?>
```

I tried every possible way that I know but still didn't got my expected result.

Comment: That form doesn't currently submit anything but its own submit button's value. You need to start by creating some connection between the rows that you hide, and the data you are submitting. That you but the rows _into_ the form, instead of the form after them, would probably be a good start here. And then you'll have to add some actual input fields into your row data. If it is just a yes/no decision for exporting you need, then a checkbox per row will probably do.

Comment: Have some read here for handling form data send/retrieve : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data

Answer (score 0):

If you want to submit the values you need to echo the table inside the form and have something to submit - a hidden field for example - then you can add disabled to the fields you do not want to submit

```
const hide = txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) === -1 : true : false;
tr[i].style.display = hide ? "none" : "";
tr[i].querySelector("[type=hidden]").disabled = hide;
```

I strongly suggest you use AJAX here instead.